# Heroku dynos, mix free and hobby

Tags: heroku

Short Question - In my Procfile I have this:

```
web: gunicorn criptoweb.wsgi --log-file -
worker: celery -A criptoweb worker -events -loglevel info
beat: celery -A criptoweb beat
```

I have a problem though, in Heroku, I can't have more than 2 Free size dynos. If I click "upgrade to Hobby" next to my dynos, all of them change to Hobby. Given that it looks like I need three dynos ... Is there a way to have 2 Free Dynos and 1 Hobby dyno?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Every app using free dynos can include one free web,  one free worker, and free usage of heroku run and Heroku Scheduler.

If you can refactor one of your Procfile processes to run either as "one-off" jobs (heroku run) or as scheduled jobs with [Heroku Scheduler](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/scheduler), then you could keep your app free.
Otherwise, you will need to upgrade to hobby dynos.

See https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2015/5/7/new-dyno-types-public-beta for more details.

Comment: I'm in a similar situation, but would like to upgrade only my web process to a hobby dyno and leave my worker process on free. Is that possible? I don't see a way to do it in the heroku admin

Comment: No. You need to upgrade both your web and worker dynos to hobby.

Comment: If I'm reading your answer correctly, then the Procfile in the question would work fine with hobby dynos. Am I reading this correctly? And thanks for your answer

Comment: Yes, the Procfile in the question should work fine with Hobby dynos, just not with Free dynos.